# Enable carrier billing on iphone

Tags: iphone, operator-keyword, billing, carrier

I want to know if i want to implement carrier billing on my iphone app in indirect way, like showing the user pop up, if you want this song, send SMS with the request xxx to the number xxx. Is this legal? will apple reject it?

Comment: For digital content Apple will reject it, since you can only use In App Purchases for digital goods.

Comment: thanks. i meant digital goods, Can i show such payment message?

Comment: What part of my answer did you not understand, Appel only allows InApp Purchases for digital goods. So in your case no, it is not allowed.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html  digital content is allowed, anyway let us go with digital goods, can i show the payment info for user to send it by SMS?

Comment: See my answer, can't make it more clear for you that that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Apple will reject you app, as clearly stated in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies):

> **11.2** - Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to
>   purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>   rejected

So yes you app is allowed to offer digital content, but the user have to pay for them with a In-App Purchase API (IAP).